# Don't understand what's wrong with my code. Can anyone help me understand why it isn't working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a program where you capture a pokemon and set their level, and when you query them it returns their level, but when I query it doesn't return the pokemon selected, just the last pokemon in the dictionary.

```
pk = {}

line = input('Command: ')
while line:
  tempq = 2
  if "Query" in line:
    tempq = 1
    qparts = line.split()
    tempname = parts[1]
    if tempname in pk:
      print(tempname, "is level", pk.get(tempname),".")
    elif tempname not in pk:
      print("You have not captured" + tempname + "yet.")
  else:
    parts = line.split()
    name = parts[1]
    lvl = parts[tempq]
    pk[name] = int(lvl)
  line = input('Command: ')

print(pk)
```

Comment: Needs better title

Comment: I can't see why it would print the "last pokemon in the dictionary". Example inputs and outputs would help.

Comment: `tempname = parts[1]` shouldnt it be `tempname = qparts[1]` instea as the varable names are different

Comment: Also what is `tempq`? Advice: do not use variable names with `temp` in them and do not assign arbitrary numbers numbers to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
qparts = line.split()
tempname = parts[1]
```

You create `qparts`, but then never use it. Instead, you refer to `parts`, which is created in your `else` block, and contains the information for whatever pokemon was named in the last non-Query command.

Try making `tempname` from `qparts` instead.

```
pk = {}

line = input('Command: ')
while line:
  tempq = 2
  if "Query" in line:
    tempq = 1
    qparts = line.split()
    tempname = qparts[1]
    if tempname in pk:
      print(tempname, "is level", pk.get(tempname),".")
    elif tempname not in pk:
      print("You have not captured" + tempname + "yet.")
  else:
    parts = line.split()
    name = parts[1]
    lvl = parts[tempq]
    pk[name] = int(lvl)
  line = input('Command: ')

print(pk)
```

Result:

```
Command: catch pikachu 50
Command: catch bulbasaur 10
Command: Query pikachu
pikachu is level 50 .
```